# Why doesn't my db update the merged tables?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, datatable, merge

I'm stuck trying to figure out why my database doesn't receive the merged data from the code below.

What the code below does is the following (PS: Its NOT clean, but it is commented!):

1. Connects to a selected XLSX workbook (always looking for Sheet1 right now).
2. Loads Sheet1 into a DataSet (DtSet) with table name "XLSheet".
3. I create a DataTable variable called dt and point it to the above table "XLSheet"
4. I connect to my applications local SQLite DB.
5. I execute a command text again the SQLite DB to DROP TABLE XLImport (the table I'm trying to import into).
6. I recreate the table using dynamic SQL to concatenate together a new CREATE TABLE statement because each XLSheet is going to have unique column titles (they come from many, many sources).  **This ensures my XLSheet and XLImport tables have the exact same schema and neither has a PK**.
7. I create a dataset from a SQLite Data Adapter that points to the new XLImport table.
8. I create a DataTable object and point it to the XLImport table.
9. I merge the two dataTables using dt2.Merge(dt)
   **10.??? How do I commit that merge back to the SQLite database via the dataAdapter???**
   Here is the code

   ```
   Private Sub cmdImportFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdImportFile.Click
   Dim bHeaders As Boolean = chkHeaders.CheckState
   Dim oFile As System.IO.FileInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(txtFilePath.Text)
   Dim sFile As String = oFile.Name
   Dim sFilePath As String = oFile.DirectoryName
   Dim da As SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter
   Dim ds As New DataSet
   Dim dt2 As New DataTable

   Try
       Dim XLConn As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
       Dim DtSet As New System.Data.DataSet
       Dim XLDataAdapter As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter


       'Create connection to selected XLSX workbook, Sheet1
       XLConn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection _
       ("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & oFile.FullName & "; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=" & bHeaders & "; IMEX=1"";")
       XLDataAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", XLConn)

       'Open and fill dataset to table 'XLSheet'
       XLDataAdapter.Fill(DtSet, "XLSheet")
       XLConn.Close()

       'Setup DataTable object
       Dim dt As DataTable = DtSet.Tables("XLSheet")

       'Connect to SQLite
       Dim sAppPath As String = Application.StartupPath

       'When debugging, this changes the AppPath value to remove the \bin\Debug portion of the AppPath
       If Debugger.IsAttached Then sAppPath = sAppPath.Replace("\bin\Debug", "")
       Dim connString As String = "Data Source = " & sAppPath & "\biodata.db;version=3;"
       Dim sDBPath As String = sAppPath & "\biodata.db"

       'Connect to DB
       conn = New SQLiteConnection(connString)
       conn.Open()

       'Drop Existing "XLImport" table
       Dim cmd As SQLiteCommand
       Dim sDROPSQL As String = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS XLImport;"
       cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
       cmd.CommandText = sDROPSQL
       cmd.ExecuteReader()
       cmd.Dispose()

       'Build dynamic SQL string for CREATE TABLE based on imported XLS file (they have dynamic headers!)
       Dim iMax As Integer = dt.Columns.Count
       Dim i As Integer = 1
       Dim sSQL As String = "CREATE TABLE XLImport("

       For Each c As DataColumn In dt.Columns
           Debug.Print(c.DataType.ToString)
           sSQL = sSQL & "[" & c.ColumnName & "] "     & ConvertXLDataTypeToSQLite(c.DataType.ToString)
           If i < iMax Then sSQL = sSQL & ","
           i = i + 1
       Next

       sSQL = sSQL & ");"


       'Create Table "XLImports" from Dynamic SQL Statement
       cmd = conn.CreateCommand
       cmd.CommandText = sSQL
       cmd.ExecuteReader()
       cmd.Dispose()
       conn.Close()

       'Open SQLite DB 
       cmd = conn.CreateCommand
       cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM XLImport"
       conn.Open()
       da = New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, conn)

       'Fill Dataset table "XLImport" from db, which is always EMPTY.
       da.Fill(ds, "XLImport")

       'Create DataTable object for 'XLImport'
       dt2 = ds.Tables("XLImport")

       'Merge the two dataTables - NO PRIMARY KEY ON EITHER DataTable
       dt2.Merge(dt)

       da.Update(ds.Tables("XLImport"))


   Catch ex As Exception
       MsgBox(ex.ToString)
   End Try

   End Sub

   Private Function ConvertXLDataTypeToSQLite(sDataType As String) As String
   Dim sNewDataType As String

   Select Case sDataType

       Case "System.Int64"
           sNewDataType = "NUMBER"
       Case "System.Int16"
           sNewDataType = "NUMBER"
       Case "System.Byte"
           sNewDataType = "NUMBER"
       Case "System.Byte[]"
           sNewDataType = "NUMBER"
       Case "System.Int32"
           sNewDataType = "NUMBER"
       Case "System.UInt16"
           sNewDataType = "NUMBER"
       Case "System.Double"
           sNewDataType = "DOUBLE"
       Case "System.String"
           sNewDataType = "VARCHAR(255)"
       Case "System.DateTime"
           sNewDataType = "DATETIME"
       Case "System.GUID"
           sNewDataType = "INTEGER"
       Case "System.Decimal"
           sNewDataType = "DECIMAL"
       Case "System.Boolean"
           sNewDataType = "NUMBER"
       Case "System.Single"
           sNewDataType = "NUMBER"
       Case Else
           sNewDataType = "ERROR"
   End Select

   Return sNewDataType
   End Function
   ```

   End Class

Any help would greatly appreciated (and just in case, Thanks in advance Mary ;) )

Comment: I only saw a few very insignificant things. for both the Drop table and the create table

`cmd.ExecuteReader`

Should be

`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`

`.ExecuteReader` returns a reader (firehose; forward only, read only) with data which you don't need
Your already associated your connection and command with

`cmd = conn.CreateCommand`

You have set the properties of the command so...

`da = New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, conn)`

can be

`da = New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)` Other than that it looks good to me. Any errors? Failure to Insert?

Comment: Thanks Mary.  The da.Update fires but doesn't seem to throw any exception.  I've run a couple of tests whereby I msgbox the record count of dt2 before and after the merge.  before the merge, it is 0.  After the merge it is 8638 (which is the right record count).  So, the records are merged, just not updated back to the database.

Comment: I think the problem might be that the datatable does not reflect any changes. The RowState would be unchanged. You can check this property to see.

Comment: Mary - I added the following
            For Each r As DataRow In dt2.Rows
                r.SetAdded()
            Next
It worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The issue was that each DataRow had a RowState of Unchanged (as Mary points out in the comments).  The solution was to add a For Each between the Merge and Update commands.

```
dt2.Merge(dt)

        For Each r As DataRow In dt2.Rows
            r.SetAdded()
        Next

da.Update(dt2)
```

+1 to Mary for that!

Comment: Wonderful! Glad you got it.